# Bezier curve-based mesh's front surface is not appearing

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

[image]
[image]

I made a bouquet by blender 2.70 for The Sims 4, but the front surface is not appearing (even in the Blender). I made it with a Bezier Curve.

How can I make it show the front surface? I'm trying to make it again, but is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: I would recommend updating to at least Blender v2.79, as 2.70 is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

In this version it could be one side surface only. In 2.81 go CURVE => 2D => FILL MODE: BOTH. If you don't won't to update the software convert it to mesh and create mirror etc.

Comment: bezier curve-3d fill full is gonna be okay?

Comment: No, in CURVE parameters change to 2D => FILL MODE: BOTH. With this 3D option there you won't see any surface.